# Windows 7 dual monitor, when opening an application, how to control which monitor the UI of the application will show up on?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I'm using Windows 7 with dual monitors. I found that when I open a new application, its window can show up on any of the monitor. Some application will show up on the main monitor, others will show up on the secondary monitor. Can this be controlled?

Thanks.

Comment: Some apps take care of their position on screen themselves, for example they remember last position. Other ones should open on the main monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Dual Monitor] for over a year and was quite pleased with it. It gives you direct control over things as which screen an app opens on and now supports up to 3 monitors. While I use Windows 8 now, which features multiple task-bars, I still miss some features from Dual Monitor.
It is a free and open source application.

Comment: Darn I have 8 monitors.

Comment: When I said 3 monitors, I was just illustrating my use my use case.  I think it's probably supports an arbitrary number of monitors but I haven't used it in a few years.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the graphics card vendor will include software that will force applications to open on specific monitors.  There is also third party software like display fusion [www.displayfusion.com](http://www.displayfusion.com/) that will manage which monitors your apps open on.