# Make Task Manager Open on Second Monitor By Default

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, task-manager

**Short Version:** On multi-monitor setups, is there a way to make a single program (such as the task manager) open on the second monitor's screen by default, *without* making all programs open on the second monitor?

**Long Version:** One issue I have with Skyrim is that it sometimes crashes.  Sometimes it'll just CTD.  Other times, it remains in a frozen state and cannot be closed.  I can alt-tab to another window, but the skyrim "window" (if you can call it that, it's fullscreen) remains on top of any other windows.

I am using two monitors, so it'll only stay above windows on the primary monitor.  But that doesn't help much, as any programs I open are opened on the primary monitor.  So, pressing CTRL-ALT-Delete to get the task manager doesn't help, because it opens on the first window, so it remains under skyrim's fullscreen window.

If I open the task manager before starting skyrim, move it to the second monitor, then close it, it will be in the last place it was when it was closed for the rest of my login session.  But if I log out or reboot, it is back to its default location, on the primary monitor's screen.

Is there any way to change the task manager's default opening location to the second monitor's screen area?

Note that simply making the second monitor the primary one is not a viable solution, and neither is making all programs open on the secondary monitor by default.  Both of those methods would mean Skyrim opens on the second monitor by default along with the task manager, putting me back to square one.  Plus, the second monitor has a smaller resolution than the primary (1920x1080 vs 1440x900).

Currently using 64bit Windows 8.1, with Classic Shell.

Comment: I believe this can be done using third party software a-la DisplayFusion

Comment: Looks like it, though it appears that the required functionality isn't supported in the free version, and I can't afford the paid versions at this time.

Comment: Also see [How to make applications open on the correct monitor when using multiple monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/738081/how-to-make-applications-open-on-the-correct-monitor-when-using-multiple-monitor)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 That question's answer is pinned upon windows remembering where a window was when it was last opened.  But as I stated above, that is not permanent: if you reboot, the window's last position is lost. But in any case, the Windows+Shift+Arrow workaround is good enough for me, so this question can remain closed.