# how to have task scheduler notifications to appear on second monitor

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

So I have created a task and assigned the trigger to activate every 30 minutes. The actions is set up as a start a program(pop up window) I just want it to appear on my secondary monitor instead of my primary monitor. Anyone know where the setting for this is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make applications open on the correct monitor when using multiple monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/738081/how-to-make-applications-open-on-the-correct-monitor-when-using-multiple-monitor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TaskScheduler does not have a setting for this. The only thing you can do is either use a script/program to move it, or see if the program can be configured to always start in that position. Most programs will adhere to saving its windows position if you hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while clicking the close button. If your program does so too, it should open in that exact location and size next time the program starts.

If not, you either have to find a program that automatically moves it for you, or script it. TaskScheduler can't do it for you though.

Comment: alright thank you for the information